# Client certificate is not sent to server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, authentication

I am trying to set up two-way SSL authentication for a SOAP web-service running on JBoss 4.2.3. We have created a CA for this purpose with a root CA and two intermediate CA-s (development and production environments).

However trying to test this setup with a client certificate signed by one of the intermediate CA-s, I have run into problems.

The server is set up with the root CA in the JVM-s `cacerts` keystore and the relevant intermediate CA in the keystore used by the Tomcat connector as the truststore. The complete Connector config is following:

```
<Connector port="443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="keystore.p12"
           keystorePass="******" keystoreType="PKCS12"
           emptySessionParth="true" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="100"
           truststoreFile="truststore.jks"
           truststorePass="******" truststoreType="JKS"
           disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Connecting with `openssl s_client` I can see, that "Acceptable client certificate CA names" lists our intermediate CA. I am also providing the correct client certificate and key in the `-cert` and `-key` options. However as far as I can understand the openssl output, the certificate is never sent. I also tried concatenating the client certificate, intermediate and root CA into a single PEM file, to present the entire chain, but this didn't help either.

The s_client command line is following:

```
openssl s_client -host localhost -port 443 -cert client_cert.crt -key client_key.key -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -debug -state
```

The same behaviour is also observerd when I try to test the service with a Google Chrome and the relevant certificates installed in Windows. The wireshark output looks the same - certificate is requested, the correct acceptable CA is presented, but the browser never even gives me a choice of certificate and an empty Client Certificate message is sent back to the server.

So my question is - what am I missing here? I have assumed that the acceptable CA list should be used by the client to decide which certificates to send, but obviously something is making the decision go otherwise and no certificate is sent. I am again assuming, that the server is configured correctly, because the expected CA is sent in negotiation, but what am I missing on the client side?

EDIT:

As requested @Bruno, I looked also at the Key Usage of the certificates. The currently used client certificate gives the followin information when printed with `openssl x509 -noout -text -in client.cer`

```
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:FALSE
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            .....
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
            TLS Web Client Authentication
```

Looking at it now - the empty Key Usage field seems to be the culprit. What values should be there? I can't seem to figure out a good phrase to google for such information. I'll probably have to look at the CA management software then.

Comment: What is the `s_client` command you are running, including all command-line parameters? (sanitize the command-line, of course). How have you configured Tomcat's `<Connector>`?

Comment: I have edited the question with the information You asked.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious question, but does the client cert have the right key usage attributes, any difference it key type too?

Comment: I have added the key usage attributes in the original post.

Comment: This is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/NSS/nss_tech_notes/nss_tech_note3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hint given by @Bruno, I investigated the key usage part of the client certificates. Turns out, that we were generating certificates with empty Key Usage attribute.

I have now configured our CA management software to generate certificates with the followin Key Usage/Extended Key Usage attributes. I do confess that I don't fully understand, what each of these does, but it made the system work for now. Hopefully I have not added anything potentially dangerous here.

```
        X509v3 Key Usage: critical
            Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment, Key Agreement
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
            TLS Web Client Authentication
```

After googling around for information about key usage bits, I also stumbled upon [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/24106/which-key-usages-are-required-by-each-key-exchange-method/24107#24107) which explained things somewhat.